# Fraction Program - Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I am currently working on a program that allows the user to select one of four methods, and test them on a list of 5 predefined fractions. The first method converts the fraction to a string, the second reduces the fraction, the third outputs the fraction as a mixed number, and the fourth represents the fraction in decimal form.

I have everything working with a couple minor flaws:

1. If the user selects the second method before the first method, the first method will print out in reduced form rather than its original form.
2. When a mixed number is negative it will print a "-" sign before each number in the mixed number (Example: -5 5/6 prints as -5 -5/-6)

Below is my code:

```
public class TestFractionBrandonBischoff
{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Create fraction array
    Fraction [] fractionArray;
    fractionArray = new Fraction[5];

    for (int i=0; i<fractionArray.length; i++)
        fractionArray[i] = new Fraction();

    fractionArray[0].numerator = -125;
    fractionArray[0].denominator = 30;
    fractionArray[1].numerator = 100;
    fractionArray[1].denominator = -4;
    fractionArray[2].numerator = 23;
    fractionArray[2].denominator = 50;
    fractionArray[3].numerator = 60;
    fractionArray[3].denominator = 40;
    fractionArray[4].numerator = 30;
    fractionArray[4].denominator = 390;

    //Prompt user to select a method to test
    System.out.println("Select which method you would like to perform: ");
    System.out.println("1. Test the toString() method");
    System.out.println("2. Test the reduce() method");
    System.out.println("3. Test the toMixed() method");
    System.out.println("4. Test the getDecimal() method");
    System.out.println("5. Quit");

    Scanner method;
    method = new Scanner(System.in);
    int methodChoice;
    methodChoice = method.nextInt();

    while(methodChoice != 5){
    //Use user input to call specific method
    if (methodChoice == 1){
        System.out.println(fractionArray[0].toString());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[1].toString());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[2].toString());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[3].toString());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[4].toString());
        }
    else if(methodChoice == 2){
        fractionArray[0].reduce();
        fractionArray[1].reduce();
        fractionArray[2].reduce();
        fractionArray[3].reduce();
        fractionArray[4].reduce();

        System.out.println(fractionArray[0].toString());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[1].toString());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[2].toString());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[3].toString());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[4].toString());
    }
    else if (methodChoice == 3){
        System.out.println(fractionArray[0].toMixed());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[1].toMixed());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[2].toMixed());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[3].toMixed());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[4].toMixed());
    }
    else if (methodChoice == 4){
        System.out.println(fractionArray[0].getDecimal());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[1].getDecimal());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[2].getDecimal());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[3].getDecimal());
        System.out.println(fractionArray[4].getDecimal());
    }
    else

    //Prompt user to select a method to test
    System.out.println("Select which method you would like to perform: ");
    System.out.println("1. Test the toString() method");
    System.out.println("2. Test the reduce() method");
    System.out.println("3. Test the toMixed() method");
    System.out.println("4. Test the getDecimal() method");
    System.out.println("5. Quit");

    methodChoice = method.nextInt();

    }

}

}

class Fraction
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

@Override
public String toString(){
    return numerator + "/" + denominator;
}

//Method to return decimal form of fraction
public double getDecimal(){
    double result;
    result = 1.0 * numerator/denominator;
    return result;
}


//Method to reduce fraction to simplest form
public void reduce() {
int n = numerator;
int d = denominator;

while (d != 0) {
int t = d;
d = n % d;
n = t;
}

int gcd = n;

numerator /= gcd;
denominator /= gcd;
}

//Method to return mixed number form of fraction
public String toMixed(){
    String mixedNum;
    int wholeNum;
    wholeNum = Math.floorDiv(numerator,denominator);

    if (wholeNum == 0){
        mixedNum = numerator + "/" + denominator;
    }
    else if (numerator % denominator == 0)
        mixedNum = wholeNum + "";
    else
    mixedNum = wholeNum + " " +
            (numerator - wholeNum*denominator) + "/" + denominator;

    return mixedNum;
}
```

If you can help me in fixing these two small errors it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 1: It is most likely because you are modifying the instance variables in reduce; I suggest using a local variable.

Error 2: You are printing the individual string of the whole number and the fraction. So basically you get the whole number, which is going to be negative, and then you perform a separate operation on the fraction, which is also negative. Then you print these two negatives; I suggest determining the sign of the fraction before hand, and then absolute value everything and print the sign at the end of the function.

Comment: Your solution to error number two makes sense to me, and I'm going to give it a try. As far as error one, I think I need to do some research for clarification. Anyway, thank you! I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @BrandonBischoff For error 1 let me clarify a bit: you change the value of numerator and denominator in that method, and numerator and denominator are instance variables, meaning that when you change those, they change permanently, and those changes are reflected in future method calls. I suggest making a variable within that method, and modifying that. When you modify instance values, this is called a functional side effect, and can be prone to errors.

Comment: P.S. I fixed error 2 by adding another if statement for when the fractional value is negative and a mixed number. In this scenario I simply multiply the numerator and denominator by -1 to get rid of the negative sign in front of the fractional component of the mixed number. This may not be the cleanest way of achieving what I wanted, but it was the simplest in my book. Anyway, thank you very much for your help again, it was very useful!

Comment: @BrandonBischoff Of course! Glad you figured out your problem!